# My variable "is not null here" using entity framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to set up a LINQ controller on my db. I am almost sure that I am really close, but this in the end baffles me:

```
[Route("tables/skillsresults/GetSoftSkillsAndSubCatsFromUser/{userId}")]
public List<JoinedResultsWithCategories> GetSoftSkillsAndSubCatsFromUser(string userId)
{
    var res = new List<JoinedResultsWithCategories>();
    var query = from ss in _migrationDbContext.Set<SkillResultsItem>().Where(y => y.BelongsToUserId == userId)
                join sc in _migrationDbContext.Set<SubCategoriesItem>()
                on ss.BelongsToSkillId equals sc.Id
                select new { ss, sc };

    if (query == null)
        return new List<JoinedResultsWithCategories>();

    res = query.ToList<JoinedResultsWithCategories>();

    res.Select(x => new JoinedResultsWithCategories()
    {
        BelongsToUserId = x.BelongsToUserId,
        BelongsToCategoryId = x.BelongsToCategoryId,
        BelongsToSkillId = x.BelongsToSkillId,
        IsSkill = x.IsSkill,
        ValueEng = x.ValueEng,
        ValueGer = x.ValueGer
    }).ToList<JoinedResultsWithCategories>();

    return res;
}
```

This is not working because:

> 'query' is not null here. on "query.toList".
>
> 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: SkillResultsItem ss, SubCategoriesItem sc>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SkillbasedMiddleware.Db.JoinedResultsWithCategories>'

How can I fix this? This controller connects to a remote database.